# How I can have the number of guilds in discord.js

Tags: javascript, command, discord.js

I want to set a presence for my bot that said something like "Watching 93 guilds" but i dont know how to do it...

My bot version is 12.2.0 in Discord.js

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you already have? Here's to steer you in the right direction: once your bot is logged in (ready event), get all the guilds your bot is in from the client object's GuildManager and check the length of its cache. The [official documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds) is very helpful. You may even be able to write an answer for your own question.

Answer (score 1):

`client.guilds.cache` is a Collection, therefore, you can use `.size` to get the number of guilds your bot is in.

```js
client.guilds.cache.size
// --> The amount of guilds your bot is in.
```

Note: You're gonna have to use `fetchClientValues` if your bot uses shards.